# For cloud machine is it a good practice to reboot periodically?

Tags: linux, performance, web-hosting

As a desktop Windows user one often find better performance if one reboot it after using if for a long periold of time. Is it also the case for virtual machine in th cloud, like EC2, Azure, or VPS?

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, I only have to reboot my virtual machines when applying security patches that require a reboot.

If you're using stable applications/services on a stable OS, you shouldn't have to do any sort of "weekly/monthly reboot" just to ensure better performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, servers don't tend to slow down with use. You want to keep your server running as much as possible. Server admins pride themselves on their 'uptime', the amount of time their server has been online for.

If you use scaling with something like EC2, server instances are created and destroyed automatically, with each new instance getting a fresh copy of the application anyway.

Comment: "Server admins pride themselves on their 'uptime'" ... even if that means sticking with a 2.4 kernel? :)